# Issue saving a retrained tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to load a model(previously saved), and save it after retraining. The loading works well, but I face issue with the saving it as below:

```
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.model_path+'.meta')
loader.restore(sess,self.model_path)#tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))            
print('Model restored')
#retrain
saver=tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, self.model_path)
```

I don't face any similar issue with saving it the first time as below:

```
saver=tf.train.Saver()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
#train
saver.save(sess, self.model_path)
```

The error I encounter is :

```
File "/share/apps/python2.7-tensorflow-1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1139, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/share/apps/python2.7-tensorflow-1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1170, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/share/apps/python2.7-tensorflow-1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 673, in build
    saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
  File "/share/apps/python2.7-tensorflow-1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 557, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
    names_to_saveables = BaseSaverBuilder.OpListToDict(names_to_saveables)
  File "/share/apps/python2.7-tensorflow-1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 535, in OpListToDict
    name)
ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: Variable_15/Adam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this message because there are two Variables with the same name in the scope. The `tf.train.import_meta_graph` reads a graph from a file and adds all operations and tensors to the current existing graph. I am surprised that `import_meta_graph` does not even fire such an exception in the first place.

See the full example to reproduce this behavior:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# tiny graph
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 2], name='input')
output = tf.identity(tf.layers.dense(x, 1), name='output')
cost = tf.reduce_sum(x * output)
# create first time u'beta1_power:0', u'beta2_power:0'
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    saver.save(sess, './adam/my_model')

    print([v.name for v in tf.global_variables()])

    # create second time u'beta1_power:0', u'beta2_power:0'
    meta_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./adam/my_model.meta')
    meta_graph.restore(sess, './adam/my_model')

    print([v.name for v in tf.global_variables()])

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    # exception as there are now two times: u'beta1_power:0', u'beta2_power:0'
    saver.save(sess, './adam/my_model2')
```

A solution is to either

- clear the graph using `tf.reset_default_graph()` before `tf.trainimport_meta_graph`
- use a new session for `tf.train.import_meta_graph`
- just load the weights using `tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, '/tmp/model/my_model')`

Comment: I used your suggestion above to 1. save a model, 2. retrain model, 3.save it again, 4. load it again. 1,2,3, but I get an error while 4. `The name 'save_1/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save_1/Const', does not exist in the graph.`